# Cannot read property 'username' of null, when trying to access id-data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to pass a users data on to its profile. I get the full data from the api and I can fetch and display it on the users page. But when I want to display the data from the user on the users profile page I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null

The routing works. But somehow I don't have access to the users info which I want to store in `information`. And I think this line should store the data of the user:

```
this.userService.getUserDetails(id).subscribe(result => {
       this.information = result;
     });
```

How can I fix that?
Here is my code:

user.service

```
 // get a list of users
  getList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users`);
  }

 // get a user's profile
  getUserDetails(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users/?i=${id}`); // why add ?i
  }
```

user.page.ts

```
 getAllFriends() {
    this.friendsList = this.userService.getList()
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
  }
```

profile.page.ts

```
information = null;
    ...
ngOnInit() {

         // Get the ID that was passed with the URL
         let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

         // Get the information from the API
         this.userService.getUserDetails(id).subscribe(result => {
           this.information = result;
         });
       }
```

profile.page.html

```
<ion-label text-wrap>
      <h6 class="subinfo">{{information.username}},&nbsp;22,&nbsp;3589</h6>
</ion-label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your component start with `information = null;` so it's normal that in `{{ information.username }}` you have this error.

A quick solution is:

```
{{ information?.username }}
```

Comment: it fixed the error. But now I just don't have anything for username its just empty

Comment: with a `console.log(result)` in your suscribe, do you have a value ?

Comment: yea, bizarrely I get the whole list and not just one user

Comment: So the problem is that you get a list :) and not just one element. I let you manage that alone ;)